# If the returned records are less than x do another query efficiency

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have one main query that selects records from today. And if today's records are less than 3, then perform another query. This is how I'm currently doing it:

```
<?php
//Select today's records
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item_info
WHERE item_info.content_time
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CURDATE( ) )
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CURDATE( ) + INTERVAL 1
DAY )
ORDER BY item_info.item_id DESC
LIMIT 9 ");

//If today's records are less than 3, select the ones from yesterday
if(mysql_num_rows($select) < 3){
    $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item_info
WHERE item_info.content_time
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CURDATE( ) + INTERVAL -1
DAY )
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CURDATE( ) )
ORDER BY item_info.item_id DESC
LIMIT 9 ");
    }

//Fetch $select
?>
```

**My main concerns are:**
-Is this a proper use of mysql_num_rows?
-Are there other ways to do this?
Usually there will be more than 3 records each day, so the subquery is just in case.

Comment: Other than the use of the deprecated MySQL extension, the logic looks reasonable to me. I don't know why `$select` changes to `$select_book_info_rec` though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is another way to do it.  Run your query to always select the top 9 records from yesterday and today.  Modify your order by clause so that it looks like this:

```
order by item_info.content_time desc, item_info.item_id desc
```

That way you don't need to check the number of records returned.

However, this is slightly different logic.  It will give a different answer than what you currently have if the number of records for today is between 3 and 9.  If that's not ok, keep what you have.

By the way, you should verify that your current code does meet your requirements.  Currently, if you get 1 or 2 records from today, you ignore them and use yesterday's data.  That might not be what you had in mind.

Comment: Yeah, it will produce a different output, I think I'll keep what I have, thanks. Btw I think the downvote was because of the  mysql use...